# Alias for an URL and not for a file in MacOS

Tags: macos, url, alias

In macOS, an alias is a small file that I can click in Finder, which represents another object in a file system and provides a dynamic link to it. Is there a way to have a small file like an alias that I can click in Finder and which represents, in the same way, an URL from an Internet site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, actually.

This works for Safari, I'm not certain about other browsers.
Just click in the omni bar to select the URL, then drag it to the desktop…

[image]

Comment: Yes it works, thanks a lot

Comment: If you accept the answer (the check mark), Tesujin will get rep for their contribution.